# PHP Contact Form Submit Error

Tags: php, html

In this form submitting, I am facing some errors.

```
1. The mail is working. But Contact form submit details not showing.
2. Its working on only gmail. Like : abc@gmail.com
3. Not working on the domain like lucky@abc.com. The mail not working.
```

Please give any suggestion.

```
<?php

       $Name = trim(strip_tags($_POST['Name']));
       $Email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['Email']));
       $Phone = trim(strip_tags($_POST['Phone']));
       $Subject = trim(strip_tags($_POST['Subject']));
       $Message = htmlentities($_POST['Message']);

       // set here
       $subject = "Contact form submitted!";
       $to = 'lachchanderdagar@gmail.com';

       $body = <<<HTML
$message
HTML;

       $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
       $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

       // send the email
       mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

       // redirect afterwords, if needed
       header('Location: thanksforcontact.php');
?>
```

Comment: Did you intend to put what looks like a real email in your posted code?

Comment: Problem 1: you aren't using $Name, $Phone, $Subject or $Message so that's why they aren't included. `$message` is not the same variable as `$Message`.

Comment: Problem 3 is going to be server-side, not something SO can help with.

Comment: 4. trim & strip_tags wont prevent header injections.

Comment: Voted to close this with 1 question out of 3. The lack of error reporting and form details makes the first point unanswerable in its current form anyway.